# Service accounts inconsistencies

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

In last few days I was trying to consolidate projects in google developers console.
I found inconsistencies mostly in permissions (service accounts) and credentials.

When new project is created it will have two service accounts (can be seen in Permissions tab in Google developers console):

```
<project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com (App Engine service account)
<project-number>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com (Google APIs service account)
```

There are no credentials in credentials tab at this point.

After clicking on tab under Compute tab, an activity of initializing Compute Engine for new project starts and it adds one another service account:

```
<project-number>@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com (Google APIs service account)
```

There are still none credentials and this state seems ok.

Unfortunately situation for most older projects is different and I observe two different cases:

1. Project have service account of compute engine type:

   `<project-number>@developer.gserviceaccount.com (Compute Engine service account)`

This account can be deleted but it seems there are credentials bound to it labeled with "Compute Engine and App Engine" in Credentials tab.
It is not possible to delete those credentials and same account will be eventually recreated.
In this project (with enabled billing) every attempt to open tab in compute engine triggers Initialization of Compute Engine but fails with "Unknown error." - not sure if it have something in common with already existing Compute Engine service account.

2. Project(s) have service account in format

   `<project-number>-<randomstring>@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

for example 123412341234-cd139d7lp7v0vjlf2l87grmpcmsh6aru@developer.gserviceaccount.com
Again this account can be deleted but it seems there are credentials bound to it labeled with "Compute Engine and App Engine" in Credentials tab.
Initialization of Compute engine on those projects (with enabled billing) finish successfully.

Are the credentials which could not be deleted cause of this inconsistencies or it can be some other project state?
What is the purpose of "Compute Engine and App Engine" credentials and why they cannot be deleted?
I am sorry for long post but I am struggling with this for few days and hope someone can shed some light in this grey area.

All old projects ware upgraded with Old appengine console > Application Settings > Cloud integration.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: I've encoutered same situation when I migrate from older console to new one: leave things in this state or if you absolutely want have clean create new projects and migrate on it or buy silver support for cloud platform and open a ticket.

Comment: Thank you for reassuring  comment I am not the only one struggling with it. I am already thinking about migrating project which is described as group 1 as it is most important for me and I cannot initialize Cloud engine on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each project has a default Compute Engine and App Engine service account, and it cannot be deleted, most likely because without it the Cloud SDK can't authenticate to the project. If the service account can be deleted, it means it isn't the default one.

The only inconsistency I'm noticing is the naming format of the service account. My older projects have [project-id]@developer.gserviceaccount.com as the default service account email address while my newer projects have [project-id]-[random-string]@developer.gserviceaccount.com instead. Besides the naming format, they appear to be behave exactly the same way.

Comment: Thank you for reply. As I described in my post I created new project and it have 3 service accounts after google cloud engine initialization and neither of them have random string in its email address (it seems to have -compute in them now).

Comment: I think what you describe as older projects they belongs to the group no. 1 because have service account in format [project-number]@developer.gserviceaccount.com. Unfortunately this group is most problematic for me because I cannot initialize google cloud engine on it. Can you tell me what other accounts you have in that project? I do have only one additional appengine service account there in format [project-id]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com. Also can you tell me if you have some credential (in credentials tab) bound to email of any of those accounts? Thank you

Comment: Both old and new projects have those under Permissions: <project-name>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com & <project-id>@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com

However, these cannot be used by other applications. The first one is to be used by appspot while the latter is to be used by the Google APIs Explorer.

Comment: I agree with what you say Ali, can you tell me if you have "Compute Engine and App Engine" credentials and to which account type they belongs to?

Comment: Yes, there are 'Compute Engine and App Engine' credentials under all projects. The type appears as 'Google APIs service account' while for old projects it appears as 'Compute Engine service account'. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it pretty much clarify what type of service accounts and credentials are for older accounts. Unfortunately it doesn't help with project where I am still not able to initialize Compute Engine but it can be completely unrelated. Thank you for help

Comment: I removed my appspot.gserviceaccount.com too. The solution is to use this api: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/repair